# Can't select and transform faces in UV Editor

Tags: uv-image-editor

I want to move a face in UV Editor I but I can't. I can't even select different faces in UV Editor. I have cursor with red circle around it in UV Editor. In 3D View I can move any faces properly.
P.S. It stretches faces if I click and drag along them.

Comment: Probably you have the UV Editor's mode set to *Paint*. Set it to **View**.

Comment: It's set to View already.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the ***UV Sculpt*** enabled. Disable it via *Uvs*-->*UV Sculpt* or press <kbd>Q</kbd>.
[image]